# Tosfot quoted Rabbi Yom Tov Myiuni

Tags: history, tosfot

For the first time I seen in Tosfot Yevamot 57b הרב רבי יום טוב מיוני

I didn't find in Wikipedia about him.

Does someone know who is this Chacham, what is his place in Tosfot constellation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely a transliteration issue. He must be R Yom Tov of [Joigny](https://goo.gl/maps/w8JdQeGPqiwi6hJ57).

Artscroll Tosfot describes him as the author of *piyutim* [Omnam Kein of the Yom Kippur evening service is one of his compositions], and disciple of Rabbeinu Tam.

His Wikipedia entry is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Tov_of_Joigny).

Comment: I understand that Joigny is York.

Comment: I would have imagined he was born in Joigny and moved to the UK later. Wikipedia also says he is French born

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This transliteration is also in Pes. ([116a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Pesachim.116a.1.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&with=all&lang=bi)). Elsewhere, [Eru. 96b](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Eruvin.96b.5.1?with=all&lang=bi), it’s misspelled “מווין” (Urbach, Baale HaTosafot p. 125). Alternatively, in Yoma ([48a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Yoma.48a.9.1?lang=bi)) he is referred to as “הקדוש” (the holy one, i.e. martyr).

Comment: RYT was originally from Joigny but moved to York. His martyrdom (1191) in fact occurred at York (or, more specifically, at [Eboracum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eboracum)). An account of the episode was documented by the contemporary, [R. Ephraim of Bonn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephraim_of_Bonn) and republished by Habermann (Gzeirot Ashkenaz VeZarfat [p. 127](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36648&st=&pgnum=134&hilite=)).

Comment: Apparently Joigny is in Yonne. I wonder whether some of these transliterated names are actually Yonne.

Comment: @msh210 not sure. the e in Yonne wouldn't be transliterated *yud*. The i or y would. Yonne in English wouldn't probably be written Yon